# Position / Normal framebuffers not rendering for deferred rendering

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, framebuffer

I am using LWJGL 3 with java. I am trying to implement deferred rendering, and having a bit of a hard time with it. For a reason that it unknown to me, whenever I try to access the position / normal framebuffers within my shader, it doesn't work, and nothing renders to the scene (the same thing that happens when you don't pass a uniform: doesn't give you an error in console, but it doesn't render). The albedo buffer works completely, and if I just draw from that the colors work, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Here's the shader that I ran, with a black screen result.

```
#version 460 core
out vec4 fragColor;

const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 16;

in vec2 vertexUV;

vec3 vertexPos;
vec3 vertexNormal;
vec4 diffuse;

uniform sampler2D gPosition;
uniform sampler2D gNormal;
uniform sampler2D gAlbedoSpec;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;

void main() {

    vertexPos = texture(gPosition, vertexUV).rgb;
    vertexNormal = texture(gNormal, vertexUV).rgb;
    diffuse = texture(gAlbedoSpec, vertexUV);

    fragColor = diffuse * vertexPos.y; // using this just as a test
}
```

Here's how I set up my framebuffers

```
        gBuffer = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);


        gPosition = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA16F, Window.getWidth(), Window.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPosition, 0);

        gNormal = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA16F, Window.getWidth(), Window.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormal, 0);

        gAlbedoSpec = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA, Window.getWidth(), Window.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer) null);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gAlbedoSpec, 0);
```

Comment: Where do you specify the draw buffers ([`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml))?